# Can I do a stable sort in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I've followed [a tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular) to add table sorting to an AngularJS app but I'm disappointed that the sort is not [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts), it seems to always start with the source data and sort it only by the key given.  I want to re-sort the contents of the table, not the source data.  Is this possible?

That is, if my source data is:

```
|ColA|ColB|ColC|
|A|1|Z|
|B|1|Y|
|C|2|X|
```

The initial presentation shows that order.  If the user clicks column Col1, there's no change.  Click again and the rows reverse:

```
|ColA|ColB|ColC|
|C|2|X|
|B|1|Y|
|A|1|Z|
```

Now if I click on ColB, what I want is:

```
|ColA|ColB|ColC|
|B|1|Y|
|A|1|Z|
|C|2|X|
```

Y and Z are still in order if the sort is stable. What I get is:

```
|ColA|ColB|ColC|
|A|1|Z|
|B|1|Y|
|C|2|X|
```

Z and Y are in the order of the source data.  (I made this example up, it may not be exactly what happens but I hope it illustrates what I'm trying to do.)

Comment: Can you spost some code?

Comment: I could copy some code from the tutorial I linked to but I don't think it would add value.

Comment: I mean code of your implementation

Comment: I assumed.  But by the time I sanitized my code it would look just like the tutorial; I wasn't creative.

Comment: I ask you for code because I don't understand this point

% I want to re-sort the contents of the table , not the source data%

If you loop  table content using ng-repeat and a data variabile that contains the content of the table why you can't sort on data source?

Comment: angular js handles sorting after getting data from database(ie. in memory)
if you don't want any delay, you need to get sorted data from database, try using ng-cloak also in you table div, it will remove flicker

Comment: Flicker I don't mind (it's not that much data) but I wish retrieving data and sorting the table were less tightly coupled.  It seems to me that the existing paradigm is "ng-repeat can retrieve and sort the data and clicking headers changes the values (orderBy and direction) used in that sort."  What's I'd prefer is "ng-repeat retrieves and populates the table and clicking the heading sorts the table"